# DX12 - Descriptor Heap Optimal approach

Tags: directx-12

I have been working on building a DX12 renderer. Currently after looking at many examples (Mini Engine, BGFX,...) I think I finally found the optimal solution for descriptor binding.
Here is the process:

- When addTexture or any add resource is called - Allocate a descriptor handle from the static shader visible heap (both CPU and GPU handles)
- When user wants to bind a descriptor set, go through all descriptors in the set and call SetRootDescriptorTable with the GPU handle that was allocated when the descriptor was created.

Is this the most optimal approach? It just involves binding 2 heaps (sampler and cbv_srv_uav) at beginning of frame and calling SetRootDescriptorTable. (We don't really use RootDescriptors since our target platform is consoles(AMD gpu) which has a root signature limit of 13 DWORDS)

Comment: With DirectX 12, there's really no "one optimal approach". The main limitation is that you can have only one ``D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV`` and and one ``D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_SAMPLER`` heap active at a time. Changing active heaps (or rootsigs or PSOs) isn't particular expensive, so it really depends on how you manage your overall scene graph. You implicitly have at most one ``D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV`` and one ``D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_DSV`` active at a time via ``OMSetRenderTargets``.

Comment: I hear a lot of people talking about categorizing descriptor tables based on update frequency. Does this mean,

if I have a VP matrix, I call SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(VP matrix cbv) only once per frame

then call SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(Model matrix cbv) per object?

Comment: The advice is the DX12 version of the DX11 performance advice about organizing updates of constant buffers by frequency. This lets you reuse CBs for longer rather than having to generate large new CB memory ranges for every draw. In general, if you can re-use something in place without having to update it, you will get better performance.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Interesting about hearing that changing active heap is not really expensive, as I remember this paper https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/08/07/direct3d-12-overview-part-4-heaps-and-tables stating that this can cause gpu flush and be avoided. Is this not really valid anymore and switching heap fine then?

Comment: It probably matters more to Intel hardware than the other vendors.There are certainly hardware design specific issues with DX 12, and it's left largely up to the developer to deal with micro differences in vendor designs (where as with DX11 the runtime tried to hide these differences).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn would be really nice to have those documented somewhere (msdn), since in my case (and I guess many other) managing heap and allocating descriptors can affect design decisions a lot. I indeed remember that switching heap on nvidia did not had any impact indeed (even tho I went into a "double buffered heap approach". I'll make it a question since I think this topic deserves to be a bit more highlighted and not buried in comments

Comment: I find no documentation on this either and the MiniEngine Dynamic Heap is only for convenience. This is especially important for AMD hardware where I think the root signature size is only 13 DWORDS so you can't have root descriptors usually.

Comment: The Direct3D 12 philosophy is largely a "this is left as an exercise to the developer", which means you as the developer have to navigate the often conflicting recommendations from the various hardware vendors. There's also a lot of experimenting still going on as to what is the best approach in practice in real titles. I'll dig around to see if there is anything concrete in this area; just be prepared for the answer to be "it depends".